# Not working BootstrapTour with meteor 1.4

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, meteor, bootstrap-tour

I am using `flowkey:bootstrap-tour` package for  BootstrapTour in meteor 1.4. but this package not working with my App. Here is my codes for this :

```
   let tour = new Tour({
     name: "tour",
     debug:true,
     container: "body",
     steps: [
     {
     element: "#test",
     title: "Title of my step",
     content: "Content of my step"
     }
     ],
     template:
     "<div class='popover tour'> <div class='arrow'></div> <h3 class='popover-title'></h3> " +
     "<div class='popover-content'></div> " +
     "<div class='popover-navigation'> " +
     "<button class='btn btn-default' data-role='prev'>« Prev</button> " +
     "<span data-role='separator'>|</span> " +
     "<button class='btn btn-default' data-role='next'>Next »</button> " +
     "</div> " +
     "<button class='btn btn-default' data-role='end'>End tour</button> " +
     "</div>"
     });


     // Initialize the tour
     tour.init();

     // Start the tour
     tour.start();
```

how to do it? 
thanks for your attention. :-)

Comment: We are having a similar problem, using ES2015 import in a Meteor 1.4 app. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @Brylie Christopher Oxley  I  used [introjs](http://introjs.com) but It does not work :-D

Comment: Ah, we are currently working with introjs, and having success. What error are you getting with introjs? Do you have a public source code repository that I can view, so I can help?

Comment: For reference, here is our current pull request with intro.js work-in-progress: https://github.com/apinf/platform/pull/1602

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
tour.start(true);
```

hopefully solves your problem